# How Can I Show Multiple Markers Google Maps with CodeIgniter Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have web application about tour and travel, In my website i have a map using Google Maps API V3. I am using CodeIgniter for Developing my web and to show Google Maps API V3 Iam using Google maps library from biostall.com.

I founded to show multiple marker from this link :
http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers

But i dont know how to show all my markers from database MySQL, because iam new in CI and still confused about the MVC Concept :).

```
    public function peta()
    {
        $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);     

        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1519'; //In this line, is a single coordinat data,  How can I get all latitude and logitude data from my table and show to my Map, Should I make a model or others..?

        $marker['infowindow_content'] = '1 - Hello World!';
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
        $data['content']='content/peta';
        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/content',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

My table is destinasi, that is structure :

id      int
long    double
lat double

I hope i can get the great answer, Iam sorry before cause my english is bad.. :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for using my library. If you take a look at the documentation PDF here:

http://biostall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Google_Maps_V3_API_Documentation.pdf

You will see on page 20 an example of how to add markers from a database. Take a look and if you have any questions just let me know.

Steve

Comment: hi biostall
it is showing this error on page load 
This page can't load Google Maps correctly.Please help me to remove this

Answer (score 0):

Biostall is best

```
 $coords = $this->model_association->getdata(); 
// Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
        if (is_array($coords) || is_object($coords)){       
                    foreach ($coords as  $coordinate) {
                 $marker = array();
                 $marker['position'] = $coordinate->latlon;
                 $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
                 $marker['title']= $coordinate->CordiName;
                // $marker['infowindow_content']=$coordinate->Address; 

 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                       }
```